# Convert DateTime to US is not good

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime, cultureinfo

I have a DateTimePicker in WPF.
The dateTimePicker give me an European Format

In my DateTimePicker, i select "01/02/2014" ( in european format )

I would like to read the value, and convert it in a shortDateString with the US culture.

**I have done this :**

```
CultureInfo m_UsCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
string str = m_dDate.Date.ToShortDateString().ToString(m_UsCulture);
```

**The str variable is** : "01/02/2014" instead of "2/1/2014"

The ShortDateString appear to be OK, but not the "ToString(m_UsCulture);".

I would like to do this in a one line please. Have you an idea for this error ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What's the value in it being in a single line?

Comment: What will you do with the string once you have it?

Comment: You're converting a string to a string - `ToShortDateString().ToString(m_UsCulture)` so how does it apply culture to the date?

Comment: What @Lloyd said, the `ToString(m_UsCulture)` is applying the culture to a `String`, not `DateTime`, it's the same as:  `"01/02/2014".ToString(m_UsCulture)`

Comment: OT: There is no such thing as European Format. We inhabitants of the roughly 50 countries which make up Europe have many different date formatting rules. Thos crazy Italialians use a decimal point as separator.

Comment: @user1929959: I don't think you meant that link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The dateTimePicker give me an European Format

That could only be true if you're using the `Text` property. I suggest you use the [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate.aspx) property, which will give you a `DateTime?` instead - and a `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format... it's up to you to format it however you want.

Then to convert them to US short date format, you should use [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) and specify `d` (for short date format) *and* the culture at the same time:

```
string str = m_dDate.Date.ToString("d", m_UsCulture);
```

Your current code is using `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` which will use the current culture, and *then* calling `ToString` **on the resulting string** which won't care about the culture you pass it.

Comment: OP is using the date: `m_dDate.Date` though converting to a string with `ToShortDateString` for some reason.

Comment: @Oded: It's not clear what `m_dDate` is here, to be honest. But my answer now shows how to convert a `DateTime` to a short date string in a specific culture.

Comment: Was commenting on the original version. And wasn't my downvote, btw.

Comment: @Oded: Sure. But fundamentally the OP's claim of "The dateTimePicker give me an European Format" indicates *either* the use of an inappropriate property, *or* a misunderstanding of DateTime. I wanted to try to correct that at the same time as providing the appropriate conversion.

Answer (score 4):

`ToShortDateString` uses the current culture, so you can't specify your US culture with this method (unless you change the current culture). I would use `ToString` instead, and the US-specific short date pattern:

```
CultureInfo usCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us");
var stringRep = yourDate.ToString(
    usCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, 
    usCulture);
```